# Upload an image with AJAX, crop portion of our choice, and save in django admin

Tags: django, python-imaging-library, easy-thumbnails

I need to give the admin the feature of uploading an image for an `ImageField` using AJAX, and then crop the portion of his choice (with a predefined dimension ratio or resolution) and then save the cropped image in the database.

I tried `django-image-cropping` and `django-ajaximage` for this.

```
#Using django-image-cropping
from image_cropping import ImageRatioField
class Alumnus(models.Model):
    photo = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)
    cropped_photo = ImageRatioField('photo', '430x360')
```

```
#Using django-ajaximage
from ajaximage.fields import AjaxImageField
class Alumnus(models.Model):
    photo = AjaxImageField(
                           upload_to='alumni_photos',
                           max_height=400,
                           max_width=400,
                           crop=True
                         )
```

While `django-ajaximage` uploads an image using AJAX, but it doesn't allow the admin to choose which part of the image he wants to be cropped, `django-image-cropping` crops an image in two steps: first we need to upload an image, save it to the db, then again we need to open the object and select crop portion, and save it again to the database, which i feel is unnecessarily cumbersome. Any suggestions?

Comment: You need to create custom widget. That task is not only for python. You need also java script on client side.

Comment: I think you should either accept the answer or specify your needs

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you'll need a JS library in the browser that does the actual cropping. Then you can use AJAX to send it to the server.

[DarkroomJS](http://mattketmo.github.io/darkroomjs/) might be just what you need. It uses the HTML5 canvas to do the image editing in browser. It's actually got a few more features than you need, but it should get the job done.

Comment: Could you please be a bit more specific about how to do that in the django admin? I don't have much knowledge about the front-end technologies.

Comment: I'm actually not very well acquainted with the Django admin, so I'm not too sure about the specifics. I did a little Googling and found this article that might be useful, though: http://www.mechanicalgirl.com/post/batch-image-upload-drag-and-drop-django-admin/

The article is about creating a drag-and-drop image uploader, but you could probably replace that functionality with a cropping library.

Answer (score 0):

The [django-client-side-image-cropping](https://github.com/koendewit/django-client-side-image-cropping) library crops the image on client-side (Using the Croppie Javascript library) to a specific size. It is compatible with django-admin sites. It does not use AJAX. It uses `InMemoryUploadedFile` to temporarily store the original file.

Answer (score -1):

django-cropper-image is an app I made for client side cropping and compressing uploaded images via Django’s app using with help cropper.js. github link [django-cropper-image](https://github.com/aneesh2usman/django_cropper_image).

```
from django.db import models
from django_cropper_image.fields import ImageCropperField
class Images(models.Model):
    image = ImageCropperField(upload_to='image',max_length=255)
```